# Entity Framework - The foreign key component is not a declared property on type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

```
public virtual DbSet<DBVolumetricObject> Volumetrics { get; set; } //this make error
```

I have the following Model

```
public abstract class DBVolumetricObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Design_Id { get; set; }
}

public class Material : DBVolumetricObject
{
    public virtual MaterialDesign MaterialDesign { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialDesign : IDBDesign
{
    ...
    public virtual List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
```

And configuration:

```
public class MaterialConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Material>
{
    public MaterialConfiguration()
    {
        Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());

        HasRequired<MaterialDesign>(x => x.MaterialDesign)
            .WithMany(x => x.Materials)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Design_Id);
    }
}
```

When I try and initialise the database via the update-database command in the package manager console I get the following error.

> The foreign key component 'Design_Id' is not a declared property on
>   type 'Material'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from
>   the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

Comment: Why are Design_Id and MaterialDesign properties in different classes? What are you trying to achieve this way?

Comment: 2 tables: some designs and many materials created from this designs

Comment: Try moving Design_Id to Material or MaterialDesign to DBVolumetricObject. I don't think you can have FK and navigation properties split into base class and a derived one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a bit of testing to verify my comment and it worked.

Your problem is that you have your FK - Design_Id - defined in base class, and navigation property for this Design defined in derived class. This way it's possible to have your FK Design_Id to be mapped incorrectly and allow it to be used as FK for multiple tables. To prevent these kinds of issues, Entity Framework says to you: put your FK property and Navigation property into same class. Otherwise, it will not work.

So solution is to make your class structure like this:

```
public abstract class DBVolumetricObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Material : DBVolumetricObject
{
    public int Design_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MaterialDesign MaterialDesign{ get; set; }       
}

public class MaterialDesign : IDBDesign
{
   ...
   public virtual List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense, you should move the `Design_Id` property to the derived class, as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893758/7108481) from [Red](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307262/red).

If it does not make any sense, you can just hide the inherited property using the `new` keyword:

```
public abstract class DBVolumetricObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Design_Id { get; set; }
}

public class Material : DBVolumetricObject
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(MaterialDesign))]
    public new int Design_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MaterialDesign MaterialDesign { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialDesign : IDBDesign
{
    ...
    public virtual List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
```

This also gives you the advantage of being able to set up the mapping using the `ForeingKey` attribute.